# Why is 'Error response from daemon' raised when i try to run a docker image?

Tags: docker

In order to apply some updates, I stopped and removed a docker container.

Then, I tried to run the updated images, and an error occured.

```
[MyServer Dir]$ ./run.sh develop
b792fa89e82617d8384ca20190b4e13132ca77127835126c209bb7682f59998e
docker: Error response from daemon: no status provided on response: unknown.
```

And `run.sh` script has the below command.

```
docker run --init -t -d -e "NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}" -e "BRANCH=${branch}" 
-e "LOG_DIR=${LOG_DIR}"  -e "LOGROTATE_CONF_PATH=${LOGROTATE_CONF_PATH}" 
-v "${BASEDIR}/${LOGROTATE_CONF}:${LOGROTATE_CONF_PATH}" 
-p ${port}:${port} --name=SOMENAME --hostname `hostname 
-f`  /bin/bash --login -c 
"chown root:root ${LOGROTATE_CONF_PATH};
pushd ${PATH};npm install;supervisord -c /supervisor/${SUPERVISORD_CONF}"
```

This script worked before, but it doesn't for now.

How can I resolve this?

Any thought appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with the docker version as some update might have happened, can you tell the version of docker you are using. You can try reinstalling runc and docker.